# Ag-Grid: how to get lastRow for custom pagination

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, ag-grid

So I want to create a custom pagination component for AgGrid. I need to display the following sign under a table (using [Infinite Row Model](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-infinite-scrolling/))

```
1 - 10 of 169
```

Here is how I set a datasource:

```
  onGridReady(params): void {
    const dataSource = {
      getRows: (rowsParams: IGetRowsParams) =>
        this.myService.getData(...)
            .subscribe(data => rowsParams.successCallback(data.rows, data.amount))
    };

    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  }
```

So as you see, I have the `data.amount` value, which represents a total amount of data entries - 169 from the example above, stored in a database.

In my custom pagination component I have an access to `GridOptions` class. How can I get the `data.amount` value, which I previously set into `IGetRowsParams`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found an answer,
here is a parent component example

```
  public gridApi: GridApi;

  onGridReady(params): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;

    const dataSource = {
      getRows: (rowsParams: IGetRowsParams) =>
        this.myService.getData(...)
            .subscribe(data => rowsParams.successCallback(data.rows, data.amount))
    };

    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  }
```

and the pagination component would be:

```
export class AgPaginationComponent {
  @Input()
  set gridApi(api: GridApi) {
    if (api) {
      api.addEventListener('modelUpdated', () => {
        console.log(api.paginationGetRowCount())
      })
    }
  }
}
```

The event listener is required to catch exact moment, when your data Observable was resolved, initially `paginationGetRowCount` will be set to 0

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest to just hold a reference to the "data.amount" in your component.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, though not a self-sufficient one. I want a single component for all my grids, so I'll have to copy-paste this silly patch all the time.